# Get the image to be placed right ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I'm currently developing a small photo cms for a friends, she uses Flickr, so that what i use to get the images, or i use a gem called Flickraw. I have to somehow know when the image is a third in a row out of three, and the second out of three, and so on. Here's an screenshot which illustrates what it does.
[image: Screen Shot]
(sorry about it is danish)

So basicly i want the middle image to be in the middle, the left to the left, and the right to the right. i have lik 8 rows .. and it is dynamicly.

Thank you!

PS. i wan't as much as possible to not use tables.

Comment: Are these images in any sort of container (div, li, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

**HTML**

```
<div class="photo-row">
    <div class="photo">Left</div><div class="photo">Center</div><div class="photo">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photo-row .photo {
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33.33%
}
.photo-row .photo:nth-child(1) { text-align: left; }
.photo-row .photo:nth-child(2) { text-align: center; }
.photo-row .photo:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xYZjL/

That's if you don't have control over the images and adding class names. If you DO have control you'd be safer to use class names in place of nth-child.

Comment: Hey, thanks! But.. i have some text under the image.. witch should be place directly under..

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically creating the page, so you can have the HTML element for each first image have `class="first"`, each second `class="second"` and each third `class="third"`.

Then you can use CSS to define `float` and `clear` layout rules for each.